# Stimulsoft "tube" element with special values

Tags: c#, asp.net, stimulsoft

Can anybody help me to understand, which of component I can use for my task?
Before charts I need to draw a "tube", which can display "danger zones". These zones mapped to second chart red points. What kind of stimulsoft element i need to use?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try top add Strips to the chart.